# Memoir class has stopped interacting with certain packages and commands

Tags: errors, memoir, setspace, bigfoot

I wrote my thesis earlier this year using the following (reduced to MWE):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang, labelfont=bf,up, textfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

%\usepackage{bigfoot}
%\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
%\DeclareNewFootnote{default}

%\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\emph{\alph{footnoteB}}}

%\usepackage{alphalph}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\emph{\alphalph{\value{footnoteB}}}}

%\usepackage{perpage}
%\MakePerPage{footnoteB}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,idemtracker=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage[a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},left=40mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,footskip=10mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\title{\fontspec [Mapping=tex-text] {Times New Roman}{Some Stuff}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\vspace{-0.5in}

%\singlespacing
Words.

\end{document}
```

I finished up around September and moved on to other projects; however, today I went back to revisit my text and discovered that somehow the document (unchanged) was no longer compiling correctly. I've identified two sticking points so far, though there may well be more:

1. If I un-comment the code for the bigfoot package above, the console says

`No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ... \else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l. 621 \newinsert\FN@savebox`

and stops compiling.

2. If I un-comment the \singlespacing command (or use any of the other line spacing commands), it's treated as an undefined control sequence.

I can use all of the above if I revert to an older class, e.g. report, but not when I use memoir (as I did for my thesis). This leads me to suspect that the problem(s) somehow lies there, but I don't really know how to pinpoint the actual issues.

Note that I updated my computer over the summer and completely updated LaTeX as part of that; everything worked just fine after this update. So far as I know, everything is still up-to-date (though at the same time I haven't seen any updates that would be recent enough to have changed things between then and now).

Edit: I compile in XeLaTeX.

Comment: Using `lualatex` or `xelatex`, I cannot reproduce the first error. But I have had to replace "Times New Roman" by another font, because I do not have "Times New Roman". To avoid the second one just use `\SingleSpacing` instead of `\singlespacing`.

Comment: Just remove the package `etex` which should not be used for any latex releases after 2015 (but actually I get no error from your document using xelatex in texlive 2016)

Comment: Okay, removing `etex` does get rid of the first error, and `\SingleSpacing` works as well--thanks to both of you!

Just out of curiosity, why does `\singlespacing` not work any more?

Comment: `memoir` emulates package `setspace`, but the `memoir` command's name is `\SingleSpacing` not `\singlespacing`. See section "Packages" in the "Introduction to the eighth edition" of the `memoir` manual.

Comment: Are you even using float, tocloft (func. build into memoir), ifthen, keyval. Memoir emulates `setspace` but slightly different. Also note that memoir comes with its own interface to set the margins, though geometry should work just as fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I know the preamble's something of a frankenstein (e.g. with the geometry margins) because I just kind of developed it as I went over the course of four years, and the switch to memoir came rather late in the process! But this is all very helpful for when I go through and try to clean it up a bit for others at the uni to use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was fixed via removal of a package,due to incompatibility

Comment: @Moriambar Is it not better to ask daleif to write an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX the problem was solved removing `etex` if daleif wants to add an answer of the question posed in the comments (ie not the main question) fine, but would be kind of strange, don't you think?

Comment: @Moriambar OK, I read only the comments